# limit JSON results using php

Tags: php, json

I am facing with a problem that my json results cannot be limited..
My json result contains a large number of data, I just want to limit the results so that i can print some of the data in my view page. How can i do that?

Here is my code

```
$post1 = file_get_contents("........");
    $products = CJSON::decode($post1, true);
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
            {
                echo "<pre>";print_r($products);
            }
```

This code prints all the contents. Please help me with this ,waiting for the response.

Output of $products.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4380
                [title] => 13 Thirteen Patch
                [barcode] => PAT-2288
                [qty] => 17
                [url] => http://www.heygidday.biz/13-thirteen-motorcycle-club-mc-fun-embroidered-quality-new-biker-patch-pat-2288.html
                [retail_price] => 4.99
                [category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => SMALL PATCHES
                    )

                [bin] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => A1
                    )

                [images] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [small] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/pat-2288-013678719880.jpg&w=30
                                [middle] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/pat-2288-013678719880.jpg&w=100
                                [source] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal/files/products/pat-2288-013678719880.jpg
                            )

                    )

            )
....................
[6619] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12921
            [title] => Special Police- BLACK Leather Key Fob
            [barcode] => FOB-0435
            [qty] => 1
            [url] => 
            [retail_price] => 8.99
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 54
                    [name] => KEY FOBS
                )

            [bin] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 382
                    [name] => F10-21
                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: share a single data sample that you are getting in `$products` ? and what you expected, I guess you should create another array with limited elements.

Comment: Thanks for posting $products. That's really helpful.  I'm not sure what you mean by "6000 data".  Do you mean individual lines or do you mean top level array elements? What do you get when you output `count($products)`?  And just to clarify, what exactly are you trying to do?  Print the first five products?

Comment: yeh, excatly, I am trying to print the first 5 products in my view page.

Comment: @PoojaKrishna if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). It takes time to research, test and write up these answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.This is how i done ........

Controller

```
$data = file_get_contents("............",true);
        $result = json_decode($data);
        $prod = array();
        $i =0;
        foreach($result as $rest){
        $product = json_decode(json_encode($rest),true);
        foreach($product as $prods){
        $prod[] = array_merge($prods);
        }
        $new_array = array_slice($prod, 0, 5);

        $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model,'products'=>$new_array));

        }
```

View page

```
<?php
foreach($product as $prod):
?>
    <li style="width: 200px;">
            <?php  
                $img = array();

                foreach($prod['images'] as $img):
                 //echo $img['middle'];
                 echo CHtml::image($img['source'],'',array('alt'=>'Image 3'));
                // $i++;
                endforeach;
            // echo CHtml::link($img,'detail');
            ?>
              <div class="list-holder">
              <h4><?php echo $prod['title'];?></h4>
              <div class="rating"> <span>$<?php echo $prod['retail_price'];?></span></div>
            </div>
          </li>
           <?php
             endforeach;
         ?>
```

This code displayed first 5 products in my view..
Thanks for all the answers provided and time...

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler answer**

Just use `array_slice` to take out the number of elements you want:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_slice($products,0,5));
echo "</pre>";
```

The pitfalls I pointed to in Ben's answer are still relevant.

**Original answer**

`print_r($products)` will print the entire array each time through the loop.  To limit the number of elements printed to 5, do:
Replace your `for` loop with:

```
for($i=0;$i<(min(5,count($products)));$i++):
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(each($products)['value']);
    echo "</pre>";
endfor;
```

Two pitfalls to watch out for in Ben Shoval's answer:

1. You should add a safeguard against going beyond the end of the array. If your `$products` has just 3 items, and you loop 5 times, you will run into an error. That's why I have the max `$i` set to `min(5,count($products)`
2. If you use the index `$i` to refer to each element, your code will fail if `$products` is an associative array (with named keys instead of indices 0,1...). This is why I use `each($products)['value']` to access the value when I don't know the key

Comment: still no change... Displays the entire data .

Comment: That' should only happen if `$products` has fewer than 6 elements. Show us your initial `$products`, and the output please. I tested before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($products);
```

To:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($products[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong code, you have printed json decode resposne 5 times.
You should check what keys in the json decoded response and then try to get specific data you want.

For example:
if you want first 5 elements of response then:

```
$c = 0;
foreach($products as $p){
    print_r($p);
    $c++;
    if($c == 5){
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the json structure first what its responding while decoding it then you can apply the login accordingly.

Comment: I saw array you posted, it consist products associative array if you want to print top 5 products then use my code in previous comment.